# Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally on AWS Cloud9 with Linux 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Working in AWS Cloud9, my script is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests


options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/home/ec2-user/environment/downloads/chromedriver')
url = 'http://google.com'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

# driver.quit()    

print(soup)
```

However, when I run the file, the run configuration hangs until I keyboard interrupt with ctrl+c. Traceback returns this:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/hubspot-marketplace.py",
> line 9, in <module>
>     driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='/home/ec2-user/environment/downloads/chromedriver')  
> File
> "/home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
> line 75, in __init__
>     desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)   File "/home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 154, in __init__
>     self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)   File "/home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 243, in start_session
>     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)   File "/home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 310, in execute
>     response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)   File
> "/home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py",
> line 466, in execute
>     return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)   File "/home/ec2-user/environment/vpy36/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py",
> line 490, in _request
>     resp = self._conn.getresponse()   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1331, in getresponse
>     response.begin()   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
>     version, status, reason = self._read_status()   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
>     line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
>     return self._sock.recv_into(b) KeyboardInterrupt
```

Just spent the last 4 hours trying to install chrome and beautifulsoup onto AWS Cloud 9. Very difficult.

Edit: I just let it run until it stopped by itself and returned `Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally`

Edit 2: Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,

platform=Linux 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64

Google Chrome 66.0.3359.117

Comment: Update the question with your _os_, _selenium/webdriver/browser_ binary version details.

Comment: Updated, not sure how to get selenium version but I just downloaded it using yum so it should be the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to establish a new *Chrome* session.

As per your question update your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.10* which pretty **old** and **ancient**
- You are using *chrome=66.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.38*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v65-67**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.10*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v66.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Python on VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715078/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor/54717263#54717263)
- [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Python on VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715078/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor/54717263#54717263)
- [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Python on VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715078/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor/54717263#54717263)

Comment: Updated chromedriver and it was successful. Thanks.