# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally while executing tests through Selenium start on Linux

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I created an application that use **Selenium** using .NetCore for use on Linux. This is my code implementation:

```
public class Program 
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Settings for chrome
        var chromeOpts = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOpts.AddArgument("headless");
        chromeOpts.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

        //Get assembly path where chrome driver is located
        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

        var driver = new ChromeDriver(path, chromeOpts, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using as driver Chrome. I downloaded it [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.9/). I also added the driver inside the folder of the assembly. In this way the ChromeDriver knows already where to find it.

On Linux I changed the folder permission using *chmod -R 777* but, when I run my Dotnet application, I get this:

[image]

Seems that *Selenium* cannot start the application.
Looking at the Exception I get:

> Cannot find Chrome binary

Unfortunately I didn't find anything similar on the web.

**UPDATE**

I reinstalled `Chrome` on my Linux machine and now the error above went away, but there is another problem now. I get this error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 4.4.0-130-generic x86_64)   
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)   
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)   
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)   
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)   
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)   
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)\   at ODS.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Update the question with _text_ based error trace logs

Comment: @DebanjanB I added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.9* which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.33*) and the recent *Chrome Browser* version (*vVersion 68.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.41**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v67-69*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.41 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium on debian server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475757/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor/57477596#57477596)
- [Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally on AWS Cloud9 with Linux 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027278/message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-on-aws-cloud9/50027645#50027645)
- [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Python on VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715078/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor/54717263#54717263)

Comment: I can't believe, this working and were I was wrong was here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html infact I downloaded the version 2.9 (I though that the version with the largest number are the recent version). Anyway, on the site that you linked to me the recent is 2.41, so this is really weird. What do you think about this? Anyway, thanks for this solution you have helped me a lot, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

first, check your google-chrome version
then download related chromedriver version i.e[image]