# Chrome crashes when running selenium python3 script as sudo

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python script where I login to a website using Selenium. Following is the snippet

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromdriver", desired_capabilities=chrome_options.to_capabilities())
WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-0"]').send_keys(username)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-input-1"]').send_keys(pass)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-login/mat-card/mat-card-content/form/div/button/span').click()
```

The script runs perfectly fine when run as `python3 test.py`. But when I run it as `sudo python test.py` it crashes with following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

What changes would I need to do to be able to run as sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start):

> A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as root user (administrator) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing '--no-sandbox' flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. Please configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.

---

### Conclusion

You need to execute your tests as a **regular user**

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is/53078276#53078276)
- [OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally while executing tests through Selenium start on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720561/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exite/51720913#51720913)
- [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed using ChromeDriver Selenium in Jenkins on Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607750/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-c/61733706#61733706)

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, there's a need to run this test case under another program which is run as ```sudo bash start.sh ...```.  In such case, is there no workaround which can work?