# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start with Selenium and Chrome on RaspberryPi

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I created some really trivial script to just open browser with specific URL it looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Once I execute this with command `python /path/to/file.py`
I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/tmp/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40,platform=Linux 4.14.69-v7+ armv7l)
```

It seems like I run out of memory or idk.
Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Check the browser version and chromedriver version compatibility. Chromedriver devs like to indicate incompatibility by crashing the whole world instead of an error message... [Here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) you can find which chromedriver supports which chrome browser. (As a side note I'm surprised that there is a chromedriver binary for rpi/arm)

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40,platform=Linux 4.14.69-v7+ armv7l)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

The version information of the *Selenium Client* and *Chrome* would have helped us to analyze your issue. However as per the discussions:

- [OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally while executing tests through Selenium start on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720561/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exite)
- [Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally on AWS Cloud9 with Linux 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027278/message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-on-aws-cloud9)

Your main issue seems to be **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.40*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.40*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v66-68**

- The current release version of *Chrome* is **v69.0**

If you are using *Chrome v69.0* there is a mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.40* and the *Chrome Browser v69.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will test it out!

Comment: `/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/pi/InstaPy/assets/chromedriver')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1024, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception`

Comment: Hi, if I specify path to chromedriver i get error as above, if I don't I'm getting same error as before :(