# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium on debian server

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, debian, selenium-chromedriver

i try to run the selenium webdriver on a debian server 8.11 and get an error.

Java: java version "1.7.0_221", OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.18)

Webdriver: ChromeDriver (v2.9.248304)

Sourcecode:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
display.start()
co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
co.add_argument("--user-data-dir=profile")
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=co)
browser.get('example.com')
browser.quit()
display.close()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/selenium", line 11, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=co)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.9-amd64 x86_64)
```

I try several solutions but nothing works...

Comment: You need a headless backend like Xfvb for pyvirtualdisplay to work (`display = Display(backend="xvfb", visible=0, size=(800, 800))`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 4.9.0-0.bpo.9-amd64 x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.9*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.9*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v31-34**

- Presumably you are using *chrome= 76.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v76.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 76**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *unknown* to us.
- You mentioned about *JDK version* is 1.7.0_221 which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.9* and the *Chrome Browser v76.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v76.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 76.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v76.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally on AWS Cloud9 with Linux 4.9.85-38.58.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027278/message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally-on-aws-cloud9/50027645#50027645)
- [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Python on VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715078/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor/54717263#54717263)
- [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium through Python on VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715078/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor/54717263#54717263)